# Jenkins workers on AWS ECS Fargate: run a few jobs in parallel

Tags: jenkins, aws-ecs, aws-fargate

I have AWS ECS cluster in Fargate mode for Jenkins workers (slaves) only.

Cluster consists of one Service called `jenkins` which has `Desired tasks` value set to 5

But when I start a few jobs which have the same label they're queued up instead of execute in parallel.

How parallel execution can be set?

Comment: Is Fargate running *any* of the jobs when you queue them up, i.e. 1 job running, 4 queued? How quickly does a job typically execute once it's running? A new Fargate task can take a couple of minutes to start up.

Comment: @bluescores thank man, I changed test jobs to be 5 min long (they were 1m) and second job runs in parallel , it just requires 2-3 min to be started

Comment: Sorry, that was a misleading comment. [You'd do that by posting an answer to your question, then marking that answer as correct.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was related to the Fargate speed - next job is queued in 2-3 minutes, so if jobs are very fast they aren't queued properly.